# Gopro hero 5 black video modes recommendation

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, action-cam

Is there a recommendation or tips for the usage of the video modes that come with the gopro hero5 black, in the meaning of resolution vs fps vs fov:

https://gopro.com/help/articles/Block/Available-Video-Resolutions-for-HERO5-Black-and-HERO5-Session

Comment: A trivial recommendation is that you use the settings most appropriate for your application.  Only you know whether you need the highest resolution setting (because it is a requirement of your broadcast client), the widest or narrowest FOV (based on your subject material), and the appropriate frame rate, either based on where you live in the world (NTSC vs. PAL), are looking for cinema or video distribution (24/25p, 30p, 50/60i, 50/60p, etc), and whether you need to cut corners to accommodate media/battery constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! I would take a look at [Abe Kislevitz's blog](http://abekislevitz.com/gopro-hero5-black/). He is one of GoPro's senior Creative Directors and has a myriad of information on his website that covers the best settings to use on GoPros.